# How to use Lodash to denormalize my arrays of objects?

Tags: lodash, flatten

I am trying to use Lodash to split my nested array and create flattened objects. **I was able to use pure Javascript to do so**, but I would like to use Lodash instead. Is there an easy way to do so in Lodash? Appreciate your help in advance.
For example:

Original array:

```
[{
    "value": 1,
    "status": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]
},
{
    "value": 2,
    "status": [
        "B",
        "R"
    ]
}]
```

What I expect is:

```
[
        {"value": 1,"status": "A"},
        {"value": 1,"status": "B"},
        {"value": 1,"status": "C"},
        {"value": 2,"status": "B"},
        {"value": 2,"status": "R"}
]
```

Comment: you are looking for something like whats in mongodb called unwind

Comment: `a.flatMap(({value,status}) => status.map(s => ({value,status:s})))` using pure js. lodash also has flatMap and map